# Https not working locally for ingress on my kubernetes cluster

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, https, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to make my ingress run over https but I'm getting `HTTP ERROR 403`, and I don't know what am I missing here.

I am trying to access them on `my-local-domain.com` and I added that entry on my `etc/hosts` file as
`127.0.0.1 my-local-domain.com` so I can access it that way.

Here's my Issuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: cert-issuer
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
```

Here's my Certificate

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: self-signed-cert
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  secretName: my-secret-tls
  dnsNames:
    - my-local-domain.com
    - www.my-local-domain.com
  issuerRef:
    name: cert-issuer
```

While here is my nginx ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  labels:
      name: ingress-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - my-local-domain.com
      - www.my-local-domain.com
      secretName: my-secret-tls
  rules:
  - host: my-local-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-api
            port:
              number: 443
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-client
            port:
              number: 80
```

nginx.conf for my web-client service

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        gzip  on; 
    }
```

And when I try to access it with `https://my-local-domain.com`

```
Access to my-local-domain.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

I also tried to run

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "//CN=my-local-domain.com\O=my-local-domain.com" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:my-local-domain.com"

kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --key tls.key --cert tls.crt -n my-namespace
```

remove `Certificate` and `CertificateIssuer` and add `tls-secret` as `secretName` in ingress, as well as added those `tls.key` and `tls.crt` to my web-client nginx and updated it to:

```
    server {
      listen 443 ssl default_server;

      ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;

      server_name www.my-local-domain.com my-local-domain.com;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

      keepalive_timeout 75 75;

      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/self-signed.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/self-signed.key;
      ssl_session_timeout  5m;

      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";
      
      location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }
```

p.s. when doing this, i run everyrhing on port `443` instead of `80`.

When I remove the `tls` part from my ingress, then it does work through HTTP. And I also tried to change my dns/host from `my-local-domain.com` to be only `localhost` but still the same. And even if I try to access `https://localhost` I get that `HTTP ERROR 403`.

Comment: Please provide us service and pod as well and maybe the setup of your nginx. From my first view i'm confused, why you're forwarding ssl to the service / pod. Is the pod using the cert? Further did you check the certificate state? How can the issuer challenge the cert, if it is locally. Also my-local-domain.com has to be resolvable from the inside of the cluster as well. Did you check it if it is working? I have many questions actually when i see this incomplete description. Maybe you can add a bit more.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek i just tried forwarding 443 to the service because I have cookie authorization and it has `samesite=none`. Nope, the api pod is not using the cert. How do you mean by `Also, my-local-domain.com has to be resolvable from the inside of the cluster as well`? Leaving the api pod completely outside, why shouldnt it work with the client pod? I added my nginx for my client, maybe i need to add ssl configuration there as well

Comment: @ManuelPolacek the is that when i comment out all paths in ingress and try to access: `my-local-domain.com` it returns `403`. Shouldnt it return `404 Not Found | Nginx`? So i think there is something on top that is not letting https work on localhost

Comment: Ok, i'm here to help you. i checked your setup again, and possibly you're mixing your protocols in your ingress. backend-protocol is https and web-client is listening to port 80, which i guess is http. It tries to communicate on a non ssl port. This is one thing. The other thing is, that you possibly need to forward headers from the nginx ingress that web-client and web-api service needs the host information. in case of you're using nginx-ingress helm chart it is controller.config.use-forwarded-headers and compute-full-forwarded-for both to true. Please give it a try...

Comment: Maybe you can also post the pod resource of web-api and web-client. Btw. i think the issuer and cert is fine, did you check it's state?

Comment: I realize now that there's a different between the annotations nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true" and nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "https". You possibly need the ssl-passtrough to let the web-client and web-api handle the ssl handshake.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek thank you for your answers. I am now listening on port `433` on `web-client` as well and I updated my `nginx.conf` to be the same as i described in the question (last part). Do i need to add anything for `forward-port` there as well? I also tried to add those two configurations for controller both by providing a configmap and by editing the controller config map as described in answers here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-set-up-nginx-ingress-for-load-balancers-with-proxy-protocol-support. Added `ssl-passthrough` as well but its not working.

Comment: p.s. cert is in `Ready` state

Comment: did the answer of akop worked for you? otherwise i will upload an example in github that we can work together on.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek it is not working as now when i do that, i get `404` and no errors are shown. I also cant see logs on `ingress-controller` that i am trying to access to that endpoint. The other thing is that when i remove everything that has to do with `tls, ssl` and i deploy it on my server, it works perfect as I have a `haproxy` that sits on top of my server and points requests there. So i can access it through `https` without providing `tls` here in my `ingress-service. But i want to make it work locally as well

Comment: Please take a look if this example helps https://github.com/manuelpolacek/k8s-https-local-ingress . The project contains an install.sh, just open it to see, what i am executing. There are 2 ingresses to show both possibilities, tls termination on nginx ingress, or ssl passthrough and ssl-termination on pod level. i set the example.com to my local ip address via hosts file to test it. Both options were running without issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but here are some advices:

1. **Determine the source of your error**
   You provide us a lot of code, but no details of the error. Is the 403 thrown by your webservice, your api or by your ingress-controller? You can check that in the error-page. Errors from ingress-controller usally contains somethink like "openresty" in footer. But it hardly depends on your ingress-controller which are you using in your k8s.
   You can also check the logs of your containers (nginx write the logs to `/var/log/nginx/error.log`). Here you can find some more detailed informations why you're getting a 403.
2. **Let the cluster handle SSL-termination**
   Don't put the ssl-certifications into the containers. It will increase hardly the complexity of your app(s).
   It is a lot easier, when the cluster take care about that. So your app can be faster deployed on other clusters with others environments.
3. **Avoid the cert-manager, when using self-signed certs**
   As you already tested, but I suggest to use the cert-manager only, when you need certificates from lets encrypt. Otherwise it will increase the complexity again.
4. **Don't mix up HTTP and HTTPS**
   Your webapi using HTTPS for the internal communication (internal means: ingress-controller -> webapi-service, which is usually unencrypted) ... but not for your web-server.
   Keep things simple - HTTPS for all or for nobody.
5. **Try to avoid url-rewrite**
   Whenever when possible, try to avoid url-rewrite. I see very often problems with it, so I suggest to avoid it.
   I know this is not always possible, but when all componets are developed by you ... why did you need it at all? Here is your ingress in "easy":

   ```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
      name: ingress-service
      labels:
         name: ingress-service
      namespace: my-namespace
      annotations:
         nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'

   spec:
      tls:
         - hosts:
            - my-local-domain.com
            - www.my-local-domain.com
         secretName: my-secret-tls
      rules:
         - host: my-local-domain.com
           http:
              paths:
                 - path: /api/       
                   backend:
                      service:
                         name: web-api
                         port:
                            number: 80
                 - path: /
                   backend:
                      service:
                      name: web-client
                      port:
                         number: 80
   ```
6. **Rootless is the best**
   Not very important for your problem, but instead of the standard nginx-image, use the unprivileged nginx-image. If your service (in this case `nginx`) got hacked, then the hacker has the same privileges like nginx. This means, he can easily install tools into the nginx-container and do very bad things.
   If you're using the unprivileged image, than the hacker can ... almost nothing. He needs a second exploit to escalate his rights.

Good luck to find your error. We are happy, when you share your next steps with us.

Comment: Thank you for these great advices. I will keep these in mind while doing Kubernetes from now on. Now when i run all services on port `80`, i have a `self-signed` cert and issuer, and now i do get `404` when i am trying to access it. And there are no logs inside `kubectl logs nginx-controller-pod -n ingress-nginx`, nor inside that pod in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: One question regarding your suggestions about the 6th point, I am using `nginx ingress` by Kubernetes, can i tell it to use the `unprivilaged image` somehow?

Comment: p.s. The thing when I remove everything that has to do with `https` and publish it on my server, its working perfect, as a `haproxy` sits on top of my server that points requests here, and i can access it with `https` without having `tls` on my `ingress service`. But i want it to work locally as well

Comment: You can keep the ingress-controller (`nginx ingress`) on the normal image. But I suggest to use the `unprivileged image` for your webapp. It seems to me, that your ingress-controller cannot determine the target (404, no logs in your container). Can you edit your question and wrote down the current configuration and the errors?